# How do I correctly implement quotename in SQL Server?

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, reporting-services, sql-server-2014

Background Info:

I have a stored procedure that is populating an SSRS report. The SSRS report is ran and exported as a CSV. It is then opened as textfile and ran through a 3 party vendor application.

The output of the text book should look like this:

```
    lid, status, i_flag,Count, pDate, iDate
    62558633,"Text Value","08/16",11,"08/16","08/16"
    78013526,"Text Value","",,"08/16""08/16"
```

My results look like this:

```
    lid, status, i_flag,Count,pDate,iDate
    19007442,"'Dir,MgmtII'",'',2,'','02/16' 
    17343623,'Text','',0,'11/15','02/16'
```

Now the code that I'm using is:

```
SELECT 
    quotename(isnull(i_flag,''''), '''') as i_flag,
    isnull(lid, 0) as lid,
    quotename(isnull(status,''''), '''') as status,
    isnull(Count, 0) as Count,
    quotename(isnull(p_Date,''''), '''') as p_Date,
    quotename(isnull(i_Date,''''), '''') as i_Date
FROM
    #Table
```

Any ideas on how I can fix this. Been stumped on this for a bit. Thanks.

Comment: I think you might be confused about what QUOTENAME does. https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms176114.aspx It is used to properly form identifiers.

Comment: I've seen that link. I also tested it before I wrote the procedure with the following code. Declare 
@text varchar(10) = 'Name'

SELECT QUOTENAME(@Text,'""') Sorry I don't know how to add the sql snippet. But that kind of accomplishes what I'm after. I'm trying to add double quotes around the rows returned from my query. Even if the row is null.

Comment: Not quite sure you mean by "Even if the row is null". There is no such thing as NULL row. I don't understand the formatting of what you say you want as output. I get wanting to handle NULL with an empty string. for that you should use 2 single quotes, not 4.

Comment: *Even if the record is null, if that makes sense. I've tried using 2 single quotes and the isn't working either. If you think I'm incorrectly doing it could you provide some example code

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If I'm understanding your question correctly (which I'm quite possibly not), I think you want:

```
SELECT 
    QUOTENAME(ISNULL(i_flag,''), '"') AS i_flag,
    ISNULL(lid, 0) AS lid,
    QUOTENAME(ISNULL([status],''), '"') AS [status],
    ISNULL([Count], 0) AS [Count],
    QUOTENAME(ISNULL(p_Date,''), '"') AS p_Date,
    QUOTENAME(ISNULL(i_Date,''), '"') AS i_Date
FROM
    #Table
```

It sounds like you have some values in fields which you wish to wrap in double quotes `"` for the purpose of exporting to CSV, plus in some cases the values in these fields might be NULL.

My suggestion above handles this by first using `ISNULL` to replace any NULL values with an empty string and then using `QUOTENAME` to wrap the resultant value in double quotes.

The crucial differences to your posted code are:

- When using `ISNULL` I replace the NULL with an empty string `''` instead of a string containing a single quote character `''''` (two consecutive single quotes within a string represent an escaped literal single quote character)
- When using `QUOTENAME` to wrap the values in double quotes, I specify a string containing a double quote `'"'` in the second parameter, instead of a string containing a single quote character `''''`.

I hope that helps you - if you're still having problems, perhaps you could provide some sample rows from your `#Table` temp table and the output you're expecting from the query so people can help you further.

As an aside, it's not good practice to use SQL reserved keywords like `status` or `count` as column names or aliases, but if you must, I'd recommend enclosing them in brackets (i.e. `[status]`) for readability (especially in SSMS or any IDE with SQL syntac highlighting or colour-coding) as I have done above.

Comment: You're welcome [user6780741](http://stackoverflow.com/users/6780741/user6780741), I'm just getting started contributing here, so I'm glad to hear this was useful for you.